# Passing array[index] to function

Tags: javascript

```
function setclass(element, classname) {
    console.log("event");
    console.log(element);
    element.classList.add(classname);   
    console.log(element.outerHTML);
}

var tpa = document.querySelectorAll("#topnav a");

for(var i=0; i<tpa.length; i++) {
    tpa[i].onclick = () => setclass(tpa[i], "current");
}
```

I don't understand why the element ins't passed to setclass via `setclass(tpa[i],...)`. console.log(element) logs "undefined" and everything that follows fails because element is undefined.

On the other hand, this works as expected:

```
var tpa = document.querySelectorAll("#topnav a");
tpa[0].onclick= () => setclass(tpa[0], "current");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(var i=0; i<tpa.length; i++) {
  (i=> tpa[i].onclick = () => setclass(tpa[i], "current"))(i);
}
```

The onclick will happen after your loop has iterated.Therefore tpa[i] will point to the last element. You might bind i trough an IIFE like in the code above, or you use the context:

```
for(var i=0; i<tpa.length; i++) {
tpa[i].onclick = function(){ setclass(this, "current")};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind creates a new function that will have this set to the first parameter passed to `bind()`.

```js
function setclass(element, classname, event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(element);
    element.classList.add(classname);   
    console.log(element.outerHTML);
}
var tpa = document.querySelectorAll("#topnav a");
var i,
    len = tpa.length;
for(i=0; i<len; i+=1) {
  tpa[i].onclick = setclass.bind(this, tpa[i], "current");
}
```

```html
<div id="topnav">
  <a>sfdg</a>
  <a>sfdg</a>
  <a>sfdg</a>
  <a>sfdg</a>
  <a>sfdg</a>
  <a>sfdg</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. However you could prevent overriding the users function trough .bind(this,tpa[i],"current")